# Angular4 - p-menu not able to see icons on menu bar

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, primeng, angular6

Currently in my project, I am using **Angular 4.1** with side menu feature.
Right side I have hamburger menu icon. On click of it, I want to show labels with icons.

Below is my code

1. **burger-menu.template.html**

> ```
> <div class="burger-menu-container">
>   <p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
> </div>
> ```

2. **burger-menu.component.ts**

> import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

Inside the class I have declared my variable like:

```
public items: MenuItem[];
```

In ngOnInit I called below method:

`this.menuItem();`

**Function Implementation:**

```
private menuItem(): void {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: this.translate.instant('burgermainmenu.mycompanyrestaurantlabel'), icon: 'home-icon', command: (event) => {
          this.arrowClick('home');
        }
      },
      {
        label: this.translate.instant('burgermainmenu.allcompanyrestaurantlabel'), icon: 'all-cafeteria-icon',
        routerLink: ['../../cafe/cafeteria-list', 'list-view', { id: this.currentLocation }],
        command: (event) => {
          this.arrowClick('');
        }
      }]
```

3. **app.module.ts**

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

> Inside @NgModule below things are already imported

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: CustomLoader }
    }),
    AsyncLocalStorageModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule
  ]
```

***Issue -*** As per above implementation, I am not able to see icons left to label in side menu.

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I am mentioning step below so in future if someone gets same issue, he can find the solution.

1. Install font-awesome

   `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`
2. Add font-awesome css file to angular.json inside style element

   `"styles": [
           "./assets/css/styles.scss",
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
           "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
           "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
           "../node_modules/moment"
         ]`
3. Now you can execute below command.

   `npm install`
4. To host the app on localhost, run below command

   `npm start`